# Get distinct count on calculated member?

Tags: ssas, olap, mdx

I'm using SSAS and created a measure group that is linked to Fact_SalesMetrics on SQL Server. In that, I have seven measures. All measures have aggregation of Sum except Sales Invoice which has aggregation of Distinct Count.

Everything works great. I need to make the aggregation of 'CustomerID' also to Distinct count, but I can't be able to. It says me error states, "The measure group has more than one distinct count measure."

So, I need to have these two measures's aggregation as DistintCount. How can I? Any help will be appreciated.

I thought to create a calculated member to achieve this but got failed as I don't know what expression I have to give!

Comment: Are there multiple CustomerID values for each invoice? If not, then a `COUNT` on CustomerID should work fine.

Comment: If not multiple values, count will exactly work. But there'll be a lot of repeating values. That's why I need a distinct count!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This helped me in getting it working!

Just go to your cube and right click. Choose “Distinct count” from the begining.

[image]

When you click ok. The new Measure Group will be created automatically. And you wont see any warning messages.

[image]

I hope this post helps anyone who was stuck on creating Distinct Count Measure like me.

Complete definition is [here](https://cemuney.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/avoiding-message-break-distinct-count-measures-into-seperate-measure-groups/):

Answer (score 2):

The limitation of a single distinct count per measure group is related to performance. To get both distinct count measures to show up in the same measure group, you can use the workaround suggested [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/cf256d9e-a47f-4745-aa9a-da14da46a7b2/ssas-multiple-distinct-counts) by Darren Gosbell.

best of both worlds...performance benefit from each DC-measure residing in its own measure group, UX benefit from having all related measures appearing in same measure group.